# How Bigquery use data stored in google cloud?

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

Guys a very basic question but not able to decipher ,Please help me out.

Q1: When we create bigquery table using below command , the data resides in same Cloud Storage?

```
bq load --source_format=CSV 'market.cust$20170101' \
  gs://sp2040/raw/cards/cust/20170101/20170101_cust.csv
```

Q2: let's say my data director is `gs://sp2040/raw/cards/cust/` for customer file Table structure defined is:

```
bq mk --time_partitioning_type=DAY market.cust \ 
  custid:string,grp:integer,odate:string
```

Everyday I create new dir in the bucket such as 20170101,20170102..to load new dataset. So after the data loaded in this bucket Do I need to fire below queries.

D1:

```
bq load --source_format=CSV 'market.cust$20170101' \
  gs://sp2040/raw/cards/cust/20170101/20170101_cust.csv
```

D2:

```
bq load --source_format=CSV 'market.cust$20170102' \ 
  gs://sp2040/raw/cards/cust/20170102/20170102_cust.csv
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When we create bigquery table using below command , the data resides in same Cloud Storage?

Nope! BigQuery is not using Cloud Storage for storing data (unless it is federated Table linked to Cloud Storage)
Check [BigQuery Under the Hood with Tino Tereshko and Jordan Tigani](https://www.gcppodcast.com/post/episode-94-big-query-under-the-hood-with-tino-tereshko-and-jordan-tigani/) - you will like it

> Do I need to fire below queries

Yes. you need to load those files into BigQuery, so you can query the data

Comment: 1. So my input dataset first resides in CloudStorage. 2 When I fire below command copy of data is moved to bigquery? Am I correct? .bq load --source_format=CSV 'market.cust$20170102' \ 
  gs://sp2040/raw/cards/cust/20170102/20170102_cust.csv

Comment: it is not moved - it is loaded into bigquery. so your original file stays untouched - and if you don't need it anymore  - you can delete it

Comment: ok Thanks. Please bear with me..Basic questions...So all my queries will refer to the data resides in Cloud Storage ? is this an external table?I see there is Native tables: tables backed by native BigQuery storage? Now my questions is how can you a load CSV file in Native table with BIGQuery storage format?

Comment: your D1 and D2 are actually loading data into BigQuery. so resulted tables ARE native tables :o)

Comment: Ok. Case1: bq load --source_format=CSV 'market.cust' 20170101_cust.csv
Case2: bq load --source_format=CSV 'market.cust' gs://sp2040/raw/cards/cust/20170101/20170101_cust.csv .. The case -1 :My source data in in local directory (Lynux landing area) and 2nd I have moved it to cloud storage.Do you see any difference the query performance will be?

Comment: loading to native table(s) and querying are two totally separate from each other. as soon as you got your data into bigquery table - from querying prospective it does not matter how you loaded it! I recommend you to read documentation (https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-storage) before asking next question(s). meantime consider at least voting on answer if you think it somehow helped you to get closer to what you need

Answer (score 0):

Yes you would need load the data into BigQuery using those commands.

However, there are a couple of alternatives

- PubSub and Dataflow: You could configure PubSub to watch your cloud storage and create notification when files are added, described [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/pubsub-notifications). You could then have Dataflow job that imported the file into BigQuery. [DataFlow Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/)
- BigQuery external tables: BigQuery can query cvs files that are stored in Cloud Storage without importing the data, as described [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/external-data-cloud-storage). There is wildcard support for filenames so it could be configured once. Performance might not be as good as directly storing items in BigQuery

Comment: Thanks for the reply. My Data files comes from external source (once Daily Not streaming) ,so I have to keep in CloudStorage for archival. Then I have to do load into Bigquery for analysis.For this I have to use Load command to load data into Bigquery.Once done data resides in both places one in Cloud Storage and other is in Bigquery?